# PHP eval in eval cannot read predifined variables

Tags: php, function, eval

Before I explain the issue, I know the risks of using eval, but there is no realy other way to do it on how my system is build, and it also is for a personal project only. (its a custom cms which when I publish it makes the physical files for me, I just made it though db so I don't need to upload files when not working remote and it is just easy).

Lets explain my issue, I have a main php file which handles all pages, all pages are stored in the db with code and all and is being executed through eval.
And the system also has a function include_db which basicly does the same as include from php normaly just from the db.

But when I access a variable defined in the first eval (main page) it can not be read out in the included eval from the db.
Weird thing is that functions can be read out though the second eval.

Any way to access variables normaly from the included eval that is being generated in the eval of the main page?
(I think it has to do because those variables are not global and its being executed in a function but I do not know a way to make every variable global :( )

Thanks in advance!

The code that is being evalled on the main page:

```
$skill = isset($_REQUEST['skill']) && is_string($_REQUEST['skill']) && isValidSkill($_REQUEST['skill']) ? $_REQUEST['skill'] : 'overall';

if(!isset($_REQUEST['player']))
    include_db('highscore_overview');
else
    include_db('highscore_player');
```

And inside the include of overview I dump the get_defined_vars() and that doesn't return the $skill I set before the include only the variables that are declared in the main index.php (database and such)

Comment: It would seem your problem has nothing to do with `eval` but with variable scope. You should post example code that shows the problem.

Comment: I added the code that I use, with some other information

Comment: php version might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all a disclaimer: You should never ever execute code from a database. That is a big security risk. It means that whenever someone is successful in gaining access to your database (using sql-injection for example) is now also capable of executing arbitrary code in php by changing the code in your database. **You really should not do that!**

If you are using code from the database to implement custom (email-)templates, please consider using a templating-engine for that like [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). Most syntaxes of template-engines are built in a way that you cannot break out of them and execute arbitrary code like you could with raw php code.

That said, i now try to answer the original question (because i cannot stop you doing things you should not do anyways). In terms of variable-scope, eval behaves like a function. If you want the variables defined inside it global, you have to manually make every variable defined inside the eval global.

You can do that by append a code-snippet to every code executed in eval that takes every local (in eval defined) variable and writes it into global scope.

```php
<?php
function include_db() {

    # ... get $code from db here ...

    # get's executed after code from db, globalizes all variables
    $code .= ';foreach (get_defined_vars()) as $newGlobalName) {';
    $code .= '    $GLOBALS[$newGlobalName] = $$newGlobalName;';
    $code .= '}';

    eval($code);
}
```

Comment: Regarding the eval issues, i know, but my system has a sytem to make fromthe db all physical files when i "publish" it :)
But regarding your answer, that get_defined_vars() does not include vars that are defined from a eval itself. only fromthe physical files. Any idea how this can be worked around? (for example it can not see the $skill defined above the include_db function)

Comment: get_defined_vars() does include variables defined in the eval if it is executed inside the eval.

Comment: If it was not executed inside my include_db function yes, it does not show items which are defined inside the first eval.

So $skill is not visible from inside the include_db function, or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: The get_defined_vars() has to be executed inside the eval. Executing it just inside the include_db is not enough, it has to be part on the code executed by eval. It does not matter if $skill is visible inside of include_db, because include_db is not making it global itself, the code executed by eval is. Code executed inside eval is like code executed inside another function, it's variables will not be visible to the caller (include_db in this case). That's why it is important that the get_defined_vars will be executed inside the eval, not inside include_db beside the eval.

Comment: Thanks, i changed it slightly to retrieve every value out of $GLOBALS and setting them by the original key, but it works now :)